# Is there any exact method to compute the integral of a fractional Brownian motion w.r.t. time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, approximation, brownian-motion

> Given $(B_H(t))_{t\ge0}$ fractional Brownian motion (fBm) with Hurst
>   parameter $H\in(0,1)$, that is, $B_H(0)=0$, $\mathbb E[B_H(t)]=0$ for all $t$, and for $s,t\geqslant 0$ $B_H$ has the covariance function
>   $$\mathbb E[B_H(t)B_H(s)] = \frac12(|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H}),
> $$
>   compute the integral of the fBm w.r.t. time:
>
> $$I = \int_{h}^{2h} B_H(s) ds. $$

Does an exact method to compute $I$ exist?

When dealing with classical Brownian motion $(B(t))_{t\ge0}$, I remember that its integral w.r.t. time could be approximated with the Riemann sum.

Is it possible to do the same with the fBm? I would say yes since $B_H$ is a bounded and continuous Gaussian process.

With the change of variable $x = s-h,\ dx = ds$, we can write $I$ as

$$
   I = \int_0^{h} B_H(x+h)dx \overset{?}{\approx} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (t_{i+1}-t_i)B_H(t_i+h)
$$

where $0 = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_N = t$ is a partition of $[0,h]$.

Is this approximation correct? Is there any better approximation?

Comment: I added the definition of fractional Brownian motion to your post since it is not exactly elementary (I have never heard of this notion in several years of studying stochastic processes, for example). I hope you do not mind.

Comment: That's ok thank you